# What format byte array stores data from PNG file?

Tags: android, image, android-ndk

I want the pixel value from the byte array obtained like this:

```
File file = new File(pngfilepathfromSDCARD);
byte[] array = new byte[file.length()]; 

BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
buf.read(array,0,array.length);
buf.close();
```

The original png file size is 320*240 = 76800 pixels, while array length is 14792.
I could not understand the format of encoding of array, I want to use the RGB values from this array for my further process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya I got the solution, I read the image using OpenCV Mat class.
and then converted it into byte array. By this i am getting the 16bit value for each pixel, which i am further processing it in jni.

Answer (score 0):

PNG files are in [PNG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

It sounds like you want to uncompress the file to an RGB bitmap.  You can do this with [BitmapFactory#decodeFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)).

Comment: by the above method some data is compressed so i does not get the correct result. Actully i want bytearray where pixel/byte is stored.

Comment: The file you're reading is compressed data.  The `decodeFile()` method will uncompress it into a Bitmap, from which you can get the pixel data (with, say, `getPixels()`).